# Remove or Customize the default popup skin in DNN 7.3

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to customize the Gravity skin in DNN 7.3. Specifically, i would like to either remove the popup page that appears to users after they login ("welcome to your website"). However I  couldn't find how to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be a Getting Started page found on the admin/page management page, but it appears that it is now loaded straight from DNNsoftware.com when you login for the first time.

I found a hostsetting that you can change in the DB to turn it off

```
UPDATE dbo.HostSettings SET settingvalue = 'false' WHERE settingname = 'EnableGettingStartedPage'
```

Once you run that you should clear the cache/restart the APP from the TOOLS menu in DNN in order to ensure the setting is updated for any future SuperUser accounts that login.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I used your recommendation and the problem is solved!